# ReactJS транспайлеры без node

Tags: windows, reactjs

Есть ли возможность переводить JSX код в JS (ES5?) код без установки 20 веб серверов 5 интерпретаторов 3 либ и одного драйвера? Тоесть без nodejs npm и всего этого зоопарка хипстерского, закончив лишь самим react'om?

Comment: По какому признаку вы отделяете сам react от всего этого хипстерского зоопарка?

Comment: да можно без ноды https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone

Comment: по функциональному признаку. react is an open-source JavaScript library for building user interfaces. библиотека, а не зоопарк серверов и кодировщиков на машине разработчика.

Comment: без зоопарка все равно будет тяжело, потому что зоопарк дает кучу всего для большого приложения. Но можно, я выше ссылку дал.

Comment: Объясните подробнее, почему у вас не получается установить 20 веб серверов и остальные либы.

Comment: @Newbie127 всё верно, транспилятор JSX туда не включен, т. к. не является частью **библиотеки** для построения интерфейсов пользователя. Он относится к **инструментарию**.

Comment: @D-side, а вроде можно же без JSX и тогда и транслятор не нужен никакой?

Comment: @Grundy естественно, то что делает транспилятор можно проделать и руками. На сайте React даже [страница об этом](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html) есть.

Comment: @D-side, ну и круто тогда :-) Напиши ответ об этом :-)

Answer (score 1):

Можно **вручную**.
Об этом [есть даже страница на сайте React: "React without JSX"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html).

Вот пример эквивалентного кода с JSX:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.toWhat}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello toWhat="World" />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

...и без него:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement('div', null, `Hello ${this.props.toWhat}`);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Hello, {toWhat: 'World'}, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Поскольку получается много вызовов `React.createElement`, предлагается сделать для этой функции псевдоним покороче, с ним становится почти прилично:

```
const e = React.createElement;

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return e('div', null, `Hello ${this.props.toWhat}`);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  e(Hello, {toWhat: 'World'}, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Избавлению от ES6 посвящена [отдельная страница, "React without ES6"](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html). В данном примере из него только интерполяция строк и объявление класса, в контексте React они заменяются на сложение строк и `React.createClass` соответственно:

```
const e = React.createElement;

var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return e('div', null, 'Hello ' + this.props.toWhat);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  e(Hello, {toWhat: 'World'}, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Если вас устраивает такой синтаксис, то пожалуйста, можете писать так.

Comment: скажите, Вы показали как обойтись без jsx, хотя вопрос был как писать на jsx без nodejs?

Comment: и за что интересно плюсуют если ответ вообще не в тему?

Comment: @OlmerDale прочитайте первые два слова ответа. И если разгадка не придёт, ещё раз перечитайте вопрос и первые два слова ответа.

Comment: Я плюсанул. Потому что вопрос состоит как бы из двух частей "как писать на jsx без ноды" и "как писать  на реакте без хипстерского зоопарка". Если первая часть освещена недостаточно подробно, то вторая более чем.